# axios - dealing with GT 1GB data

Tags: node.js, axios, http-get

I have an API I have to pull data from. Unfortunately the powers that be will only allow me to get all the data or none. The problem is that in some cases this data is 800MB is size and some other end points return more than 1GB.

I am getting the following error

```
if (encoding === 'utf8') return buf.utf8Slice(start, end);
                                          ^

Error: "toString()" failed
    at stringSlice (buffer.js:560:43)
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:633:10)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/apps/microservices/ln_warehouse/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:197:41)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Not sure if this is related to the size of the data response, but it only happens with the large data sets.

Is there a way of streaming data out of axios as it is received?